# how to mention friends in facebook open graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

as per the documentation over here

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/tagging/#mentions

I am able to post on behalf of the user of my application and as well tag user's friends by using app access token.

but I have problem with mention. As said in documentation my message formate is

```
Testing @[MyFriendsFacebookId]
```

in facebook it look's same  `Testing @[MyFriendsFacebookId]` , it is supposed to be

```
 Testing [Name of my friend with the link to his ACCOUNT]
```

Please advise.

Comment: Are you using "tag" in your post parameters?

Comment: Rupesh Patel, any luck?

Comment: @Pavelfljōt not yet , given up actually :)

Comment: @RupeshPatel I ended up adding field of fb "Profile" typ and sending user id in data section and showing name (as proper FB user name) using {profile} in story attachments.

Answer (score 1):

1. at first, the YourFriendFacebookId is got from /me/taggable_friends api, not from /me/friends api。I have made this error before. and the /me/taggable_friends api need additional permission for non-developer and non test users, you must require it from facebook. the api link is here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/taggable_friends

[image]

2. if you mention friend in a custom action, you still need require "tag" permission for you custom action when define it. (but I don't know whether need and how to require "tag" permission for common action). If it is not work, I think you may still need to require "User Messages" permission.

[image]
<sub>(source: [akamaihd.net](https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/t39.2178-6/10935998_1542751369325383_2049849528_n.png))</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the details Spark, this will be helpful for others

Answer (score 0):

you can't mention friends in posts via app as far as I know. There's a discussion here on SO on the same topic. I'll search it for you.

Comment: chekout the open graph documentation ; its possible as they says , but just don't work for me .https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/tagging/#mentions

Comment: even I am able to tag people that also not possible with graph api

Comment: have you asked the permission to tag in your app's dashboard? I had read on SO that this isn't possible but maybe the answer is outdated. If you've requested the permission to tag and your actin got approved with that permission, then it's simply a bug.